# GLassfish error in log port 1527

Tags: deployment, glassfish

Hi i have this error message :

Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused

when im doing a deploy, my EAR reaches 50% and it goes back to 0, and I get this error, does anyone know why it happens? im missing some configuration?

Help me please!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the JavaDB that is default DB on glassfish. Navigate to glassfish4/javadb/bin and run startNetworkServer script to start the db on port 1527